# Replacing text from a file with regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to read an XML file and substitute `dp` with `sp` everywhere in the text where the textSize attribute is used. For example `android:textSize="8dp"` will be replaced with `android:textSize="8sp"` if the below file will be processed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="8dp"/>

    <View            
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I have the following code:

```
patternDp = /android:textSize=\"[\d]+dp\"/
content = File.read("layout/some_layout.xml")
content.gsub!(patternDp, "???")
```

I know that the second parameter of the `gsub!` method is the string that will replace the pattern, and I have some difficulties on how to use it in a such way that the method not to replace the whole `android:textSize="8dp"` with `sp`, but only the `dp` string from the pattern.

Would appreciate any help, if my approach is not correct please let me know how I could solve the problem in another way.

Comment: Don't parse XML with regex; Regular expressions aren't good tools for that, except in the most simple cases where you control the generation of the XML. If the XML format changes your pattern will be very likely to break. In *THIS* case, you can get away with a simple `gsub` because you're not trying to match tags, but for the most part you'd be better off using Nokogiri and learn to parse XML/HTML the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capture the digit(`\d+`) and use `\\1` in replacement to obtain the capture.

```
input = input.gsub(/(?<=android:textSize=")(\d+)dp"/, '\\1sp"')
```

`(?<=android:textSize=")` checking whether the digits are after the `android:textSize="` text or not so that it doesn't pick others.

However, if you do not wish to use lookbehind `(?<=...)` then this simple one.

```
input = input.gsub(/android:textSize="(\d+)dp"/, 'android:textSize="\\1sp"')
```